# Catch a PL/SQL procedure's RETURN value in command prompt?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, command-prompt, sqlplus

Currently I'm using

```
%testvar%=sqlplus usr/password@schema @test.sql
echo %testvar%
```

where `test.sql` calls the procedure using `BEGIN END` block , and saves the returned value in a string variable named `x` , now how do I return this to command prompt ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Add DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to your procedure and print the value
2. Run SQL*Plus
3. Connect to oracle
4. start spool
5. run the procedure
6. stop spool
7. exit from SQL*Plus
8. read the value from the file

Something like this:

```
sqlplus /NOLOG
SQL> CONNECT user/password@alias
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
SQL> spool /tmp/proc_result.txt
SQL> BEGIN
2    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello_world');
3    END;
4    /
hello_world
SQL> spool off
SQL> DISCONNECT
SQL> EXIT
```

At this point you want to use shell to read the value.

Answer (score 1):

I finally Used This, PS i had to get the mapped directory path from the directory name:
$1 here is username/password@schema

```
    var=`sqlplus $1  <<+ | grep "Delimeter!*" | sed -n -e '/\[[^]]/s/^[^[]*\[\([^]]*\)].*$/\1/p'
    SET SERVEROUT ON
    SET ECHO OFF
    SET LINESIZE 4000
    DECLARE
      A VARCHAR2(400);
    BEGIN
        SELECT directory_path into A from all_directories where directory_name='$input_dir';
dbms_output.put_line( 'Delimeter! [' || A || ']' );
    END;
    /
    exit
    +`
```

Note: Those are **`** not **'**

Answer (score 0):

A procedure can only return a value through an OUT parameter, however a function can return a value which can be stored in a variable. I am not sure how you are trying to return the value through a procedure but it seems what you are trying to do would work better if you had written a function.